# how to change padding if the element has a child

Tags: html, css, sass

I have an element which has a child element.

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child">
</div>
</div>
```

So here is the styling for parent element:

```
.parent {
padding: 20px;
}
```

So child component displays whenever the error is triggered. So, what I am trying to do when there is an error (the child div is going to be triggered and will be displayed) I want parent's padding 0 and I want to add it to the  child's bottom.

So it should be basically something like this:

```
.parent {
padding-bottom: 0;
.child {
padding-bottom:20px;
}
}
```

But whenever I have a child. Is it possible to achieve this via css? How can I achieve this?

Comment: you cannot have a css selector that will set the style of a parent element having further conditions like a child. Unless using [:has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) but that's a very very recent feature mostly unsupported. You would need to use js to achieve something like that.

Comment: @diegod is right. I would add that you probably don't need it. In your basic case, you could have `.child:last-child {paddin-bottom: 0;}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)